# how to build kernel module with makefile?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to build this kernel module.

[martinezjavier/ldd3](https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3)

but this page's indication doesn't work.

I think makefile can't find where KERNELDIR is.

I cloned linux kernel source in home directory

and type like this:

```
$ export KERNELDIR=/home/"username"/linux/

$ sudo make
```

and here's error message.

> /home/"username"/DeviceDriver/ldd3/misc-modules/jit.c:31:32: fatal
>   error: linux/sched/signal.h: no such file or directory.

but that header file is in cloned linux's directory.

please help me.

I'm trying this on **Ubuntu 16.04**.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't post external links - what if the link goes down/is malicious etc

Comment: Why are you using arbitrary Linux source instead of the source for the kernel running on the system?

Comment: #Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams because that page's instruction said like that. I'm just beginner of this area. So I have not much solution.

Comment: I tried to using source for the kernel on my system, but I still have problem. redefinition of struct, function, and others. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: `#include <linux/sched/signal.h>` only works for kernels 4.11.x and later. For lower-numbered kernel versions, use `#include <linux/sched.h>` instead.

Comment: The problem is probably because `sudo` is stripping out your environment variables, so `KERNELDIR` is unset when running `sudo make`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you for your comments. I tried to doing make without `sudo` command but there are other issues. I will try another solution. Thank you so much to you and other comments.